# Error While Evaluating Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

***Please Avoid This Question****
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{27^x - 9^x - 3^x + 1}{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1+\cos x}}$$

I tried to solve it by applying the L'Hospital's rule.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{27^x\ln27- 9^x\ln9- 3^x\ln3 + 0}{(-1/2)/\sqrt{1+\cos x}}$$

Now simply apply the limit,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1\ln27- 1\ln9 - 1\ln3}{(-1/2)/\sqrt{2}}=0$$

But the correct answer in my textbook is $8\sqrt{2}(\ln3)^2$

Where am I doing incorrect?

Edit: I did a silly mistake while Solving it.

Comment: rationalise the denominator. now write the 1- cos x as $2 sin^2 x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ is $\dfrac{-\sin x}{2\sqrt{1+\cos x}}$

Comment: Oh! I did a Silly Mistake.